# Cannot find ROW_NUMBER() function in mysql 8.0.17?

Tags: mysql, row-number

I setup my web service by using package AppServ : Apache + PHP + MySQL, which is download from
https://www.appserv.org/en/

Mysql version is 8.0.17, and phpMyAdmin is 4.9.1

When I tried to use ROW_NUMBER() function inside phpMyAdmin, it always told me some errors.
Eventurally, I feel my Mysql might not include this function.

Is it possible? and how to verify it (mysql hasn't row_number()) and how to solve it?

Comment: What were the errors? Can you show an example of a query that you tried and the exact error message? Perhaps ROW_NUMBER() is supported but you made some other mistake in your query.

Comment: I copied sql command (contain row_number()) inside phpMyAdmin, it told me some error  before I run it. When I tried to run it , it told me "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax".

Comment: @John put the query here!

Comment: my sql  command such as "SELECT  custid, email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email ) AS row FROM customers;"

Comment: Execute `select version();` to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is a reserved word in mysql 8.0.2+ according to the [documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

This should work:

```
SELECT custid, 
email, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email ) AS `row` 
FROM customers;
```

Or you can ditch `row` for something non-problematic such as `AS rn`.

Notice that partitioning by email and ordering by it at the same time doesn't make much sense.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a3980e84b374df14e9ef1b139603161)

Comment: no, doesn't work

Comment: @John care to elaborate? Are you getting an error?

Comment: the same error as before.

Comment: @John edited my answer to include a fiddle. Can you check it?

Comment: I am checking, it seems work, thank you!

Comment: In the fiddle, the row number is always 1; it's not functioning.

Comment: @MattSmith it is working... The example is just too small, notice that it's partitioned by email. https://dbfiddle.uk/UFuUS15b here's if you add one more row with an email that already exists.